# How to load and save data in PyQt4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to write an app to deal with data saving and loading with QTableWidget.

I want to write a more complex app, so, I use many pyqt classes to define different pages.
Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        load_file = QtGui.QAction("Load", self)
        load_file.triggered.connect(self.loadFile)
        save_file = QtGui.QAction("Save", self)
        save_file.triggered.connect(self.saveFile)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        file = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        file.addAction(load_file)
        file.addAction(save_file)

        table = Table()

        self.setCentralWidget(table)

    def loadFile(self):
        load_file = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "./", "All files(*)")
        if load_file:
            with open(load_file, "r") as load_data:
                data = eval(load_data.read())

            Table().filling(data)

    def saveFile(self):
        save_file = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "./", "All files(*)")
        if save_file:
            with open(save_file, "w") as save_data:
                save_data.write(repr(DATA))

class Table(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self)

        self.setRowCount(4)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.itemChanged.connect(self.getData)

    def getData(self):
        data = []
        for row in range(4):
            row_data = []
            for col in range(2):
                if self.item(row, col):
                    text = self.item(row, col).text()
                    row_data.append(str(text))
                else:
                    row_data.append("")
            data.append(row_data)
        global DATA
        DATA = data

    def filling(self, data):
        for row in range(4):
            for col in range(2):
                new_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("")
                self.setItem(row, col, new_item)
                self.item(row, col).setText(data[row][col])

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The app can save data filt in the QTableWidget, but cannot show the loaded data.
[image]
I want to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because when calling `Table().filling()` you are creating and filling another table, it is appropriate to make the table member of the class.

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        [...]

        self.table = Table(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

    def loadFile(self):
        load_file = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "./", "All files(*)")
        if load_file:
            with open(load_file, "r") as load_data:
                data = eval(load_data.read())
                print(data)

            self.table.filling(data)
    [...]
```